# ASP .NET 2.0.50727 in the server response header. How to be sure is EOL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, eol

I found this version of ASP .NET in the header Server as a response from a web server. How can I verify if this version has still an active support or it is ended? On the microsoft website I can't find official info on this specific version.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick google and I quickly found this

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework

> Support for .NET Framework 2.0 ended on July 12, 2011.

Which is for all versions of it.

You should try to move up to 3.5 SP1 at minimum.

Comment: I've already read it but I was not sure .NET support end date is the same of ASP. NET support end date.

Comment: Why would you think that?